# what is "a block containing no statements"?

Tags: swiftui

In the official [ViewBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) method: [buildBlock()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder/buildblock()), it says:

> Builds an empty view from **a block containing no statements**.

But obviously, when I tried to use a block containing no statements, I got an error:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // ❌ cannot convert value of type: () -> () 
        //    to expected argument type   : () -> _
        HStack { /* a block containing no statements */ } 
    }
}
```

So, can we or how do we give `HStack` (or any other ViewBuilders) a block containing no statements?

Comment: This builds in Xcode 12.0.1.  What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @vacawama I'm still playing around with Swift Playgrounds for iPad, :) I'm learning SwiftUI just for fun ^_^.

Comment: @vacawama Do you know how to give a block containing no statements before Xcode 12.0.1? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Ok with Xcode 12.0. I assume it is Playground issue.

Comment: How about `HStack { EmptyView() }`?

Comment: @vacawama I can live with that until the next update for the Swift Playgrounds for iPad, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun ...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    private var never: Never?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        never
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know `Never` is a `View`, but why is it a `View`? What is it good for?

Comment: Read the Apple documentation carefully - just for fun,  and... you got the answer to your question.

Comment: I have done some investigations and I found something interesting about `Never` and why it is a `View`. In the definition of `View` protocol, `body` is a computed property: `var body: some View`, so from there we know the body of a `View` is again a `View`. Then there comes another problem, why the definition won't cause an infinite loop? - the body of a view is again a view of which its body is still another view, and so on ... Now comes the secret, I found that the body of all the elementary views (such as `HStack`, `Text` ,...) returns `Never`, this is where the loop ends.